# Anonymize Query for posting

Tags: sql

I was curious if there is an easy way to change SQL code from what the code actually is to something like:

```
Select
   col1
  ,col2
  ,case when col3=5 then col4/10 else col4 end

from table1
```

I ask this because a lot of the code I have questions on contains business logic that I can not share and with the column/table names it becomes real obvious what is going on.

I have in the past manually changed some of the code. But some of my code is what I consider to be complex and long so it takes a very long time to make these changes.

Basically I am wanting to anonymize my code.

Comment: I haven't a clue what you are asking here. Can you clarify a little better for us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest solution I know of is using [Sentry One's Plan Explorer](https://sentryone.com/plan-explorer). It doesn't simplify the code how you want, but it does anonymize it.

This article by Aaron Bertrand covers the overview and limitations of this option: [SQL Sentry Plan Explorer v2.7 : Better Anonymization](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/plan-explorer-better-anonymization/).

Comment: I will look into this thank you @SqlZim. Anonymize is the word I was looking for but unable to find.